# Does mockk support suspend inline?

Tags: inline, suspend, mockk

It looks like coEvery hangs when I am trying to mock suspend inline function.

The code below works if remove inline modifier

Function in storeApi:
`suspend inline fun getAllStores(): List<Store>`

Test code:
`coEvery { storeApi.getAllStores() } returns allStores`

I'd like to have a way to mock suspend inline function, not only suspend

Comment: Did you find a way around it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple answer - no, and not possible:

As other mocking frameworks, mockk relies on bytecode level instrumentation for methods. When you mark a function as `inline` the compiler will not generate a method on bytecode level though.